# How to scroll bitmaps?

Tags: android, bitmap, scroll

I have one image view (assigned one bitmap to it) and another bitmap (Transparent) for painting. How it is possible to scroll this bitmap and background bitmap at the same time to be painted at different places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood you are trying to draw on top of a image. If thats the case, create a custom view and get the image using BitmapFactory. After you get a bitmap object, use its copy method and use that copy for the canvas of the view.
   Now you can override the onDraw method of a custom view and draw anything on top of it.

This view can be added to the layout, and scrolling will happen to the view.

Edit: Sample Code

Ok this is some code that might help you. I dont have the time to go through all your code.
But I tried to understand your requirement.

I am showing the code for an activity, its xml and custom view

Activity.java

```
public class DrawDemo extends Activity {
    private FrameLayout container;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.draw_demo_layout);

        container = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.sc);        
        container.addView(new DrawView(this));
    }

    public void drawHandler(View target){
        container.addView(new DrawView(this));
    }

    public void clearHandler(View target){
        if(container.getChildCount() != 1){
            container.removeViewAt(container.getChildCount()-1);
        }
    }
}
```

draw_demo_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" 
        android:id="@+id/sc" android:scrollbars="horizontal"  
        android:layout_weight="1.0">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/chips"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Draw"
        android:onClick="drawHandler"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Clear"
        android:onClick="clearHandler"/>     
</LinearLayout>
```

DrawView.java

```
public class DrawView extends View {

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
            ,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        p.setStrokeWidth(5);
        canvas.drawLine(50, 50, 100, 150, p);
        canvas.drawLine(100, 150, 20, 50, p);
    }
}
```

This activity has a framelayout which has a imageview as the base which holds the bitmap.
We add a custom draw view on top of it and do our drawings on it.When we want to clear the drawing we remove the drawview and add another one if we need to draw again.
    This might not be the most efficient way. But should get you started.

Comment: it,s happened but at the time of erasing the image also erasing (getting black color on view), i want only erase paint , and according to your answer scrolling is possible before paint i want scroll between paint.

Comment: Well a quick hack I would do was create 2 views on a framelayout. The base view will be the imageview with your image and the secondview will be a custom view with a empty bitmap and you add ur drawing to that view and clear the bitmaps as you wish but the underlying imageview should be visible. Apply scrolling to the outer frame layout. This seems like a hack. You might be able to get this all done by using a single view and stacking 2 bitmaps.

Comment: see my code and tell me where i have to change http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38493970/Full.java

Comment: Well you should make your framelayout scroll according to the size of the imageview and the drawview should take the size of the imageview. There posts in SO about scrolling in both directions. Check them out.